# Is it the correct way to use for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I seen weird `for` loop syntax in C++. Please see following program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num, count = 0;
    int array[]= {1,1,2,3,4,1,3,2,9,8,7};
    cout<<"Which number would you like to know about how many times it appeared?"<<endl;
    cin>>num;

    for (int i:array)
    {
        if (i == num)
            ++count;
    }

    cout<<"Number "<<num<<" appeared "<<count<<" times in the array"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It is successfully run on **GCC Linux** platform.

Reference link [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/97309/).

So, My question is, **Is it the correct way to use for loop in C++?**

Also, Is `for (int i:array)` equivalent to `for ( int i:array ; ; )`?

Sorry for my poor english. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: for syntax is `for (int i=0;i<imax;i++) {}` for you I recomend   `for (int i=0;i<sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);i++) {}` .

Comment: @nick_n_a that is one way to write a `for` loop, it is not the only one. The one in the example is C++11 range-based for (as already linked)

Comment: @EdgarRokyan Thank You sir...

Comment: is it that hard to google for the syntax online?

Comment: @Mox: Yes it is.  Google is not good at punctuation (which is critical here).

Comment: It is a good way to make sure you traverse all the elements of the container and avoid off-by-one errors. With a "classic" for loop, you have to check the initialization, test and increment parts to know exactly what it does. If you need to go through all of the elements, the range for states the intent more clearly.

Comment: For this particular example, it would be better to not write the loop at all: `count = std::count(std::begin(array), std::end(array), num);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are now (since C++11) *two* distinct syntaxes for for-loops, the old C-style:

```
for (initialization; test; increment)
```

and the new

```
for (declaration: container)
```

In the new syntax, the `declaration` declares a variable which is successively given the value of each element of the container.  Common values of "declaration" are `auto val`, `const auto val`, `auto& val`, and `const auto& val`, depending on whether you want a reference to the value in the container or a copy, and whether you want the value constant or not.

Both syntaxes are correct.  It rather depends what you want to do in the loop.  My preference is to use the range based for unless I am going to need the loop counter or iterator ... in which case I fall back on the old style for.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for for the gory details of the specification (and what is meant by "container").

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `for (int i:array)` iterates through each element in the array, compared to `for (int i = 0; i<sizeof(array); i++)` which creates a counter that automatically increments on each iteration of the loop. The counter can then be used to access elements of the array with `array[i]`

As for which one you'd use, it depends on what you want to do. In your example there isn't a need to keep track of which iteration of the loop you are on, so the former will work fine. If you wanted to, say, print the iteration number each time then you would use the latter.

P.S. your English is perfect :)

Comment: I wouldn't go as far as "perfect" - I can definitely tell the OP is not a native speaker - but it's better than my German, and I have been employed in a company where German was the working language.

Comment: Well no not perfect, but easier to read than a lot of native English people! Definitely better than "poor" as OP describes.

Comment: @Sinfieldd, Martin Bonner - Thanks for answer.